# select and "click" on an option from an option box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i have a scrollbox , and i want to click one of the options, the scroll box is like

```
<option value="AT">AUSTRIA</option>
<option value="BY">BELARUS</option>
<option value="BE">BELGIUM</option>
<option value="BG">BULGARIA</option>
<option value="HR">CROATIA</option>
```

and i use :

> ```
> document.getElementById("order_billing_country").value =  "BG";
> ```

and it works fine , but the problem is that the website when you click on one of the options appears a button that is hidden. doing with my code it will select for instance bulgaria but the button related to bulgaria will not appear , so it's like that ti's select bulgaria but it doesn't "click" on it , there is a way to let it click on it ?

Comment: Hi Maria. Yes, there is a way. Please post more of your code, at least the part where we can see html for button as well.

Comment: it depends sometimes it's a button , others time is a text depends' from the country

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It doesn't seem to be quite clear to me what is the problem... And I would like to help.

Comment: I have this scrollbox , when i select one of the option and i click on it (for instance bulgaria on the page appear a text like "ok you choose bulgaria" if instead i  use this document.getElementById("order_billing_country").value =  "BG"; the text doesn't appear just like if i select the option but don't click on it